# Compare columns from two Oracle databases, matching field is date, one has time one doesn't

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I need to compare and find a percent error for several columns from two different Oracle databases. DB1 DATE_TIME column only has date, no time (DD-MON-YY), DB2 DATE_TIME column has date and time. Each row represents one hour, and DB1 is in the correct order by hour, but with no actual times. Need the relevant columns to match up between id and date_time (specifically, hour), but I've found that a WHERE clause testing for DATE equality will only give the DB1 entry corresponding to 12:00:00 AM because of not having times as part of the date format in DB1, so I'm not able to to compare the correct entries for other times. How can I get around this?

Code below to better illustrate:

```
SELECT db1.field1, db2.field1, db1.date_time, db2.date_time
FROM db1, db2
WHERE db1.date_time = db2.date_time AND db1.id = X
ORDER BY db2.date_time DESC;
```

This query runs, but none of the data actually matches because it's only returning the first row of each day from DB1 (corresponding to 12:00:00 AM).

I've thought of somehow inserting corresponding time stamps to DB1 DATE_TIME column based off position so I can include time in the WHERE, but not sure how to do that, or if it will even work. I've seen that running a test query using BETWEEN day1 and day2 (instead of =) returns the results I want for a given range of days, but I'm not sure how to implement that in the JOIN that I'm trying to do with DB2.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try along `WHERE TRUNC(db1.date_time) = TRUNC(db2.date_time)`, which does remove the respective time portion?

Comment: That's basically how I am running the query. The date_time in db2 is VARCHAR type, so I'm using `WHERE db1.date_time = TO_DATE(SUBSTR(db2.date_time,1,10), MM-DD-YYYY)`. So it is comparing only the dates. It returns the correct rows from db2, but just repeats the same 24 rows for each day from db1. I think I somehow need to **add** a time parameter into db1.

Comment: Oh, wow - so my answer is good for nothing, I'll remove it. It would be best to alter the table in db2 so the date_time column has the date data type. If you want to explain how the rows are "ordered" in db1, we may be able to help with a solution. You do surely need to add a time parameter to db1.

Comment: Yeah I explained that poorly, the rows in db1 follow the correct order of hours through the day (i.e. first row with date_time 01-JUN-16 is the 0:00:00 entry, second row is 1:00:00, last row is 23:00:00). They just don't have times actually entered in the table. 

Also, I did try to change db2 date_time to DATE type using the SQL Developer GUI, and it gave an error saying the column had to be empty to change the type. I left it alone after that... I suppose I could create a new column with correct type and copy the dates.

Comment: Re-reading it a few times: It seems you actually do want to align by hour of the day, rather than by day alone. If so, use `TRUNC(date_time, 'HH24')` in order to preserve the hour. However, if **DB1.date_time** has just dates but no time component, you'd need to add it in.

Comment: As you seem to be able, to sort the records as if the hour were included, (with a recent Oracle version) analytic functions should allow you, to do so. If, e.g., you were sorting by **db1.date_time, db1.id**: `db1.date_time + RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY db1.date_time ORDER BY db1.id) / 24` should provide you with the right **date_time** value.

Comment: This seems close to what I need, I had never heard of rank(), can you explain a little more? I'm relatively new to SQL. Is your example code supposed to allow me to add the time component into db1? Or should I use it in the actual join query?

Comment: Not knowing the overall context, I thought primarily of using it in the query, you are working on. But if it makes sense to you, you might want to use it for an update to your table. - [Analytic functions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions004.htm) in general do allow calculations at the row level, which would otherwise require to join the original data to some aggregate of it. -- If there is still something substantial missing to get you going, please, provide more detail.

Comment: @Abecee - just note that rank() starts at 1 and times start at 0, so you should first subtract 1 (in parentheses) and only then divide by 24.

Comment: @mathguy: Yeah - sure. Thanks for the heads-up. Too late to edit the comment, though.

Comment: I believe I understand the intent of how to use rank(), I tried `SELECT db1.field1, db2.field1, db1.date_time, db2.date_time
FROM db1, db2
WHERE db1.date_time + rank() over 
(partition bydb1.date_time order by db1.unit_id)/24 = TO_DATE(db2.date_time,'MM-DD-YYYY') AND db1.unit_id = db2.unit_id AND db1.unit_id = X
ORDER BY db2.date_time DESC`;

Comment: and got this error: RA-30483: window  functions are not allowed here
30483. 00000 -  "window  functions are not allowed here"
*Cause:    Window functions are allowed only in the SELECT list of a query.
           And, window function cannot be an argument to another window or group
           function.
*Action:

Comment: Analytic functions go into the `SELECT`! - And remember @mathguy hint about the need to subtract **1** from `RANK()`.

Comment: Yes. -- Let's include the necessary fields and do the join afterwards. Or start with updating **DB1.date_time**.

Comment: Understood that too late after posting comment, I see now. Question though: why would I divide the rank by 24? Isn't the rank going to give me a sequence of integers from 1 to 24, corresponding to the sequence the of the rows, for each date in db1.date_time? also, noting that running the query is not giving my a list from 0 - 23, instead I'm getting all 0's...

Comment: Can you describe how i would use rank() to do the update properly?

Comment: Yes - you get numbers from 1 to 24. But one hour in Oracle date arithmetic is **1/24**.

Comment: Writing up an answer with both options (`SELECT` and `UPDATE`).

Comment: another quick comment while you're writing your answer, I see an issue with using rank() how you described. When i `order by date_time, unit_id` the rows are all in order, and that's the order I want the times to reflect. However, when I call rank() (partition by date_time, order by unit_id), all the unit_id values are equal, so the rank is 1 for everything. almost like I need to call rank() without an order specified... also, quick thank you for helping me out. I don't have enough reputation to move this to chat unfortunately (sorry @mathguy)

Comment: But then, you'd not need **unit_id** for the sorting at all. Did you list `TO_CHAR(date_time, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')` to double-check / verify the actual content?

Answer (score 0):

If you care about performance, I would suggest that you create a function-based index on `db2`:

```
create index idx_db2_datetime_date on db2(trunc(datetime));
```

Then, you can use this construct in the query:

```
SELECT db1.field1, db2.field1, db1.date_time, db2.date_time
FROM db1 JOIN
     db2
     ON db1.date_time = trunc(db2.date_time) 
WHERE db1.id = X
ORDER BY db2.date_time DESC;
```

For this query, an index on `db1(id, date_time)` is also helpful.

The indexes are not necessary for the query to work, but the function-based index is a nice way to write a performant query with a function in the `ON` clause.

Note:  Learn to use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.  Never use commas in the `FROM` clause.

Comment: Apologies, I'm very new at SQL. Could you explain this a bit more? I tried running the code and it didn't solve the problem, so I believe I must be leaving out other important information about the problem.

Comment: As the OP explained, date_time in db2 is varchar2, so trunc(date_time) will not work.

Comment: @mathguy . . . I see nothing in the question that says that the representation is `varchar2`.  In fact, the title explicitly says "matching field is date, one has time one doesn't".  Wait, I see something in a comment.

Comment: Right... That happens about 80% of the time on SO. It is what it is.

Comment: my mistake, should have included that in OP. Yes, date_time column of db2 is type `varchar`. Been using `to_date` to convert it in the queries.

Answer (score 0):

For a `SELECT`, you might want to try along:

```
SELECT db1_.field1, db2.field1, db1_.date_time, db2.date_time
FROM (
  SELECT
    id
    , field1
    , date_time + (RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY date_time ORDER BY id - 1) / 24 date_time
  FROM DB1
  ) DB1_
JOIN db2
  ON db1.date_time = TRUNC(db2.date_time, 'HH24')
  AND db1.id = X
ORDER BY db2.date_time DESC;
```

If you prefer to get the hours added to **DB1.date_time**, please, try:

```
UPDATE
  DB1 TDB1
SET TDB1.date_time =
  (SELECT
     d_t 
   FROM
    (SELECT
       id
       , (date_time + (RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY date_time ORDER BY id) - 1) / 24) d_t
    FROM DB1)
  WHERE id = TD1.id
  ) DB1
;
```

Sorry, no suitable test data to verify in full at this time.

Please comment if and as this requires adjustment / further detail.

Comment: leaving soon for the day, will try this first thing tomorrow, and may resume commenting on this answer. feeling very close to solving this! appreciate the help

Comment: Remembering your comment about using `TO_DATE(SUBSTR(db2.date_time,1,10), MM-DD-YYYY)` the `SELECT` would require adjustment - the specifics depend on your hour format.

Comment: just tried checking what happened with `TO_CHAR(date_time, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')`, as you suggested in other thread, and there are the times! I had a hunch they were actually in there somewhere, or else how would the rows have been in the correct order by ascending hour each day.  Knowing this, I believe I can just run the query comparing the dates as `char` instead of `date` type, as like I mentioned db2.date_time is already `varchar` type. Hopefully any further issues with my task shouldn't have anything to do with this problem anymore. thank you for helping!